# SVG used in WinUI 3 is always blank

Tags: xaml, svg, winui-3

According to everything I have read, in WinUI3, I should just be able to use a path to an SVG-Image in an `Image` element. But even though that works fine for `.png`s, it only gives me blank images for `.svg` files.

My XAML:

```
<NavigationViewItem Tag="Clients">
    <NavigationViewItem.Content>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Vector/Client.png" Width="30" Height="30"/>
            <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Vector/Client.svg" Width="30" Height="30"/>
            <Image Source="/Assets/Vector/Client.svg" Width="30" Height="30"/>
            <Image Source="Client.svg" Width="30" Height="30"/>
            <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Vector/ClientX.svg" Width="30" Height="30"/>
            <Image Width="30" Height="30">
                <Image.Source>
                    <SvgImageSource RasterizePixelHeight="30" RasterizePixelWidth="30" UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Vector/Client.svg"/>
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
            <TextBlock Text="Betreiber" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </NavigationViewItem.Content>
</NavigationViewItem>
```

The result:

[image: Screenshot]

The `Client.png` and `Client.svg` both have the Build Action "Content" with "Copy if newer".

I'm also getting no error when referencing a file that definitely does not exist, like `ClientX.svg`, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: mybe setting a Stretch="UniformToFill" and Margin can help

Comment: Did you try to put this in blank project after adding the file to it? `<Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Vector/Client.svg" Width="30" Height="30"/>`. Should work assuming you copy the `.svg` file to the output directory.

Comment: Can't reproduce any problem. "Copy If Newer" is not needed. Please post a reproducible sample somewhere [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved my problem, and it turned out it had little to do with WinUI:
My SVG-file had a strange `viewBox` set.

This is what the `<svg>`-tag looked like before:

```
<svg id="Icons" height="512" viewBox="0 0 60 60" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

And when I removed the height and width:

```
<svg id="Icons" viewBox="0 0 60 60" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

The image became visible.

What was apparently happening was that the image was much bigger than the viewbox, so WinUI showed my image and made the 60-by-60 viewbox into a 30-by-30-pixel square, as I requested, but the actual visible content was somewhere to the right, outside the visible area of the control.